# Unable to login after password change, having home directory encrypted

Tags: login, password, encryption, login-screen

I have ubuntu mate.
I have recently changed my password using the passwd command. I know now that I have made a mistake because I also have my home directory encrypted with the previous password.

Consequently after enter my new password at login screen it return me back to the login screen.

Can someone please help me?

I am able to enter to grub boot menu and shell, i am also able to log into guest user.
Sorry if the topic is duplicate but I haven't found the same question

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your password back with the passwd command. Then, with and encrypted home directory, you have to change your password with the graphical tools.

[image]

This is a security feature to prevent root , or someone with root access, from changing your password and thus accessing your encrypted data.

For additional details see [Changing home folder encryption after changing user password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640146/changing-home-folder-encryption-after-changing-user-password)

Comment: The problem is that i don't have access to the terminal itself, to revert to my previous password

Comment: Boot to recovery mode and change your password or ctrl-alt-F2 and log in.

Comment: You are most welcome.

Comment: It took me literary 1 hour to figure out. Thanks